# Access sent parameter in onResponse of retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I create a request with retrofit2 and send parameter to server, how can access sent parameter in onResponse?

```
  retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("baseAddress")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ApiBase serviceSetParam = retrofit.create(ApiBase.class);
    Call<String> myCall = serviceSetParam.setParam("data1","data2");
    Callback<String> myCallback = new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

            //i need access data1 & data2 Here !

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String mResponse= response.body();
            } else {
                Utils.Log("unSuccessful");
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            Utils.Log("onFailure");
        }
    };
    myCall.enqueue(myCallback);
```

here the send param method:

```
  @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("set")
    Call<String> setParam(@Field("param1") String param1, @Field("param2") String param2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in onResponse method of your request, test this code:

```
                try {
                    BufferedSink bf = new Buffer();
                    call.request().body().writeTo(bf);
                    Log.i("params are",bf.buffer().readUtf8().toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: This does not do anything to get the URL parameters.

Comment: I need to implement similar code in Android, want to make sure I am importing the correct library. For `BufferedSink` and `Buffer`, is it `okio.Buffer` and `okio.BufferedSink`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the original Request from OkHttp.

`List<String> pathSegments = original(response.raw()).url().pathSegments();`

given:

```
static Request original(Response response) {
  while (true) {
    Response prior = response.priorResponse();
    if (prior == null) {
      break;
    }
    response = prior;
  }
  return response.request();
}
```